# How to set up a Form submit button tied to service call that must finish before submission in Angular/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

I am trying to set up a form submission, where the form itself contains a field that is used elsewhere in the application and thus has its own service tied to it. What I aim to do is set up the submit button for the form to perform the service call for that particular field, wait until it finishes with a successful response, and then continue on to the regular form submission logic.

Here is a simplified version of what I have tried so far:

```
async onSubmit(form) {
    if(specialField) {
        const response = await this.updateSpecialField();
    }
    // I will leave the rest of the form submission abstracted away
}

async updateSpecialField() {
    this.specialService.updateField().subscribe(then => {
        this.specialService.loadingFields$.subscribe(data => {
            this.loading = data;
        });
    });
}
```

In this case, the service call is made but it happens in the background and always finishes after the form submission goes through. Since I have not had luck with going that route, I have tried to use await and promises to have the service call finish before continuing.

Here is a different approach to the same updateSpecialField function:

```
async updateSpecialField() {
    let updatedFieldResponse = await this.specialService.updateField().toPromise();
    return Promise.resolve(updatedFieldResponse);
}
```

In this case, the return line never seems to execute and the form submission does not occur. I get a successful response back from the service but it does not resume executing lines of code from where I expect that it would.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
async onSubmit(form) {
    if(specialField) {
        const response = await this.updateSpecialField();
    }
    // I will leave the rest of the form submission abstracted away
  }
  
  async updateSpecialField() {
    return this.specialService.updateField().pipe(
              switchMap((_: any) =>
                this.specialService.loadingFields$.toPromise().then(data => {
                    this.loading = data;
                })
              )
            ).toPromise();
  }
```